# Pandas: Trouble Counting Capitals

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame, `df`, containing a column called `_text`.  I'm trying to count the number of capitals in each piece of text like this:

```
text_capitals_count = [sum(1 for char in x if char.isupper()) for x in df['_text']]
```

Instead of giving me the count, if there's a capital anywhere in the piece of text, `text_capitals_count` is set to 1.

What am I doing incorrectly?  I thought this would count up the number of capitals in each piece of text...

Thanks!

Comment: That's correct. Can you show a sample dataframe where this does not work?

Comment: `df['_text'].str.isupper().sum()` will give you number of rows with all capitals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and select first character of text by `[0]`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'_text':['FFfgdFF','TT gd F','GG','EE EE U']})  
print (df)
     _text
0  FFfgdFF
1  TT gd F
2       GG
3  EE EE U

a = [sum(1 for char in x if char[0].isupper()) for x in df['_text'].str.split()]
print (a)
[1, 2, 1, 3]

a = [sum(1 for char in x.split() if char[0].isupper()) for x in df['_text']]
print (a)
[1, 2, 1, 3]
```

Another solution:

```
df['a'] = df['_text'].str.split(expand=True)
                     .apply(lambda x: x.str[0].str.isupper()).sum(axis=1).astype(int)
print (df)
     _text  a
0  FFfgdFF  1
1  TT gd F  2
2       GG  1
3  EE EE U  3
```